# Linear Analog Optocoupler Arrangements

Tags: operational-amplifier, opto-isolator

For optocouplers with a second photodiode for feedback for linearization, what is the functional difference between the two positive input stage configurations below?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhFmes.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I realize that normally you need to apply the feedback signal to the inverting input to get negative feedback, but it but it seems to me that the independence of the photodiode and LED in the optocoupler enables you to mess with things a bit by flipping the output. So to me it seems that in this case it is possible to get negative feedback by applying the feedback signal to the noninverting input.

In app notes I only ever see the second configuration so I don't know if it's just habit arising from the fact that in most circuits you must apply the feedback signal at the inverting input to get negative feedback, or because it actually doesn't work for some reason. Personally, I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: The 2nd configuration behaves a lot like a standard inverting opamp, with D3 providing the negative feedback which would normally be provided by a resistor between the inverting input and the output. The 1st configuration probably doesn't really work at all - the output will always be high as far as I can tell.

Comment: @brhans Would it not work? In my mind the applied voltage initially places the noninverting input above 0V and the inverting input. That then drives the LED which causes the photodiode to drag down the voltage at the noninverting input towards ground. Is that not correct? I realize you can't normally apply negative feedback to the noninverting input but it seems to me that the independence of the photodiode and LED in the optocoupler lets you mess around with things a bit.

Comment: Did you swap the locations of the LED and photodiode in the second image? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: @Hearth Oops. It's been corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @brhans I realize you can't normally apply negative feedback to the noninverting input but it seems to me that the independence of the photodiode and LED in the optocoupler lets you mess around with things a bit by flipping the output. In app notes I only ever see the second configuration so I don't know if it's just habit arising from the fact that in most circuits you must apply the negative feedback at the inverting input so, or if I don't see it because it actually doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Well, in the 1st configuration, the only way you're going to get 0v at the non-inverting input with a non-zero Vin is if D1 sinks enough current to behave as a dead short...

Comment: @brhans But if that's the case, isn't the same thing true for the second circuit as well except with the inverting input? Is that even a problem? R1 is there after all so no supply or signal is actually being shorted to GND. D1 only needs to sink \$I= V_{in}/R_1\$

Comment: Have you seen this one: https://docs.rs-online.com/65b6/0900766b814ca846.pdf ? Pages 10 and 15.

Comment: @devnull Yes. I have seen that one but since you drew attention to it, I did notice that the first configuration does appear on page 10. And a comparison is made on page 16, but the comparison only consists of saying that both inverting and noninverting configurations will work. Perhaps there are no functional differences?

Comment: yeah - I guess in this case looking at the opamp as ideal and assuming that negative feedback needs to make the 2 inputs equal doesn't really work - the non-inverting input doesn't need to get to 0v.

Comment: Yes. A bit disappointing regarding the amount of info to explain how the "practical" version is better than the "basic" one, which is explained with details. Not much beyond the possibility to add C1 between the inverting input and output. Figure 17 also uses this feedback but changes the output with a PNP.